# rails: backbone-on-rails gem file naming conventions responsible for error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I'm following along with Ryan Bates RailsCast Backbone.js tutorial. This image is a screenshot of his tutorial.

[image]

Notice, in the views/entries/ directory, there is a file called "entries_index.js.coffee"

When I generated my scaffolding, that file was simply called `index.js.coffee`

This may be significant because Ryan instantiates the view in the router with `EntriesIndex`.

```
index: ->
    new Raffler.Views.EntriesIndex()
    $('#container').html(view.render().el)
```

and then in the entries_index.js.coffee file renders the template

```
render: ->
    $(@el).html(@template())
    this
```

which, for demonstration, is just supposed to put this  in the container div

```
<h1>Raffler</h1>
```

However, when i do the same, I'm getting this error in Firebug

```
   view is not defined
[Break On This Error]   

return $('#container').html(view.render().el);
```

Because of the difference in the names of the files `entries_index.js.coffee` v `index.js.coffee`, I was wondering if it's significant that Ryan instantiates the view this way (i.e. with camel case taking the place of the underscore)

```
new Raffler.Views.EntriesIndex()
```

If I change it and try

```
 new Raffler.Views.Index()
```

I get the error

```
 Raffler.Views.Index is not a constructor
[Break On This Error]   

new Raffler.Views.Index();
```

Any ideas how I can get back on track?

Answer (score 0):

I retyped the code and it's working now as is. This must have something to do with indentation in coffee script.